# Scala Mock Object Creation

Tags: scala, mocking, superclass

Is there a way to create an object of a given type that overrides a subset of methods and throws runtime exceptions for the rest of the methods?

It doesn't even need to have access to any implementation of the superclass. It just needs to have the same type at compiletime and runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That pretty much is what  a [ScalaMock](http://scalamock.org/) mock object does out of the box — methods you've set expectations on do whatever the expectations tell them to do, all others throw an ExpectationException.

What's your use-case?

Comment: I just don't want to write the boilerplate code for all the methods that are not implemented (see comment on dhg's answer). I suppose scalamock suffices. But it would be nice if I didn't need to go to external libraries.

Comment: In PowerMockito, we can use the pattern "whenNew(MyClass).thenReturn(mockMyClass)" when someone new an instance of MyClass, it will receive mockMyClass instead of the real instance. 

Can we do similar things in ScalaMock? I spent whole day for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

As Paul said, ScalaMock is a good way to go.

But I wanted to point out that you're just describing basic inheritance:

```
class OriginalClass {
  def methodToRun() = { println("called OriginalClass.methodToRun") }
  def methodNotToRun() = { println("called OriginalClass.methodNotToRun") }
}

class MockOriginalClass extends OriginalClass {
  override def methodToRun() = super.methodToRun()
  override def methodNotToRun() = throw new RuntimeException("you weren't supposed to run this!")
}
```

Then, in your code, where you were expecting an `OriginalClass` object you can pass in a `MockOriginalClass` and it will throw errors when you call the wrong things.

Comment: The main issue is that I just don't want to add the boilerplate `throw new RuntimeException(...)` for all the not-to-run methods. It would be supercool if there was a language feature that filled those in for you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused how the system would know which methods were allowed and which disallowed if you didn't explicitly tell it.  Pasting `throw new RuntimeException` doesn't seem like too much work.

Comment: The default would be that all methods were disallowed (throw exceptions). You would specify the implementation for the other methods.

Comment: Oh, i see.  Then definitely a mocking framework is what you want because a mock object requires you to specify all allowable behavior.  The default, not specifying any behavior, would mean no behavior is allowed.  And you would explicitly allow each valid behavior.